# Connecting Coda to local Wordpress install hosted with Mamp Pro

Tags: mamp, vhosts, coda

I have been using Coda and regular version of Mamp for local development for longtime without getting into this permission mess. I recently, upgraded to Mamp Pro and setup it with VHosts. I have a site `example.com` with it's root path set to `/Users/john/Sites/example`. I have set the owner and group to `www` in Mamp Pro.

The moment I got all this configured I started having problems with Coda. It keeps asking me the username and password to edit the local files at `/Users/john/Sites/example`. I guess I have to enable FTP on my Mac and then add a site in Coda to stop it asking me to enter username password for every single file. However, I have no idea on how to get this working. I am using Lion 10.7.2

Additionally, I have setup etc/hosts file for pointing example.com to 127.0.0.1

UPDATE: Though the accepted answer by @mini does not directly answer this question. It is still an elegant solution with seamless integration with Coda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using DesktopServer instead (along with Coda 2). Unlike MAMP, you can work on template theme files directly with WYSIWYG preview, LAN share for mobile device testing (with WordPress, -not just HTML sites), enables AirPreview to work with WordPress, copy, import/export to live sites, etc. Setup is easy as it manages your vhosts, database, and project files in about three mouse clicks:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pw9-F8etBPY